# XQuery variable has not been declared

Tags: xpath, xquery

I know this error happens when I forget to wrap a sequence in parenthesis. But I was playing with this query for a while and put parenthesis where I saw fit. I still cannot get this query to work

```
         <ul>
            {for $R in doc("exp.xml")/exp/R
            let $groups := tokenize($R/@an_attribute, '\s')  

            return (
                <li>
                    <div>{$R}</div>

                    <ol> 
                        for $group in $groups
                        return (<li>{$group}</li>)
                    </ol>
                </li>
                )
            }
        </ul>
```

Comment: I can't see why this was closed as off-topic. You made a simple mistake that many users make, you described it clearly, and having the solution "on file" is likely to help other people.

Comment: @MichaelKay because SO is not syntax-error-fixing service.

Comment: That's a puzzling remark. If someone makes a syntax error and gets obscure diagnostics that don't help to resolve it, asking the question on SO and getting an answer seems perfectly reasonable and useful thing to do.

Comment: +1 - think it might be specific to XQuery as a language:  not knowing where to put brackets, and parentheses for sequences can lead to sometimes "weird" error messages  (and i think this specific one is common)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the brackets to run the FLOWR inside the  tag!

```
<ol> 
{
    for $group in $groups
    return <li>{ $group }</li>
}
</ol>
```

and that's why you're getting the "variable has not been declared":  it's not setting the for loop variable `$group` at all